# iPhone SDK mySQL

Tags: mysql, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm starting on a new iPhone project, and this application mostly relies on MySQL. I have a MySQL database running on my computer, and I need this application to send queries to the server to gain information. One example is creating and logging into an account.

I have successfully done this on my windows vb.net application, but I know that Objective C will be harder. This is basically getting text from the SQL database and displaying it on the iPhone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, on a good day, you don't let your user's query the database directly. Instead, you have a dynamic web page that sits as middleware between the database and user.
This way in the dynamic web page you can spit out XML (or something just as useful like CSV) and parse it on the user's end.

Comment: +1 Storing connection data in code is dumb, unless he's doing a mobile mysql client. In which case do NOT use a middleware.